# render an ejs file with post and ajax in node js

Tags: node.js, ajax

I'am using node js and trying to render some files.
Now when user go to page register first thing is to see if the database was connected if no then we render technicalProblems.ejs if yes we continue and run the code inside the get and render register.ejs and thats fine and works well but we also check about the database connection when user submit the form and if it is disconnected i wanna  show the user that we have technical issues and to replace  register.ejs with technicalProblems.ejs.

```
app.get('/register', checkDatabaseConnection, (req, res) => {
  res.render("register.ejs");
});
app.post("/register", registerLimiter, checkDatabaseConnection, (req, res) => {
 res.render("register.ejs",{ data: JSON.stringify(data) });
});
function checkDatabaseConnection(req, res, next) {
  connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.render("technicalProblems.ejs");
    } else {
      console.log('Connected to the database.');
      next();
    }
  });
}
```